# How can make table for my android app

Tags: java, android, xml, native

[image]

I want to make such kind of table(as shown in the picture) for my android application. But i can't figure it out. How can i do it?
       Please give me some sample example or tricks that will help me to do this table.

Comment: It should be fixed size or dynamic like as ListViee?

Comment: do you want the borders as well?

Comment: it should be dynamic @ Eldar Mensutov

Comment: Yes i want exactly like the picture @ SMR

Comment: you would have upvoted and accepted

Answer (score 1):

Layout which you are expected can be obtained with `LinearLayout` with attributes `layout_weight` also. But as you are more familiar with `TableLayout`.

`TableLayout:`

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:shrinkColumns="2"
    android:stretchColumns="2" >

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Text1" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Text2" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Text3" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Text4" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="@android:color/black"
                  />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Text5" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

One two `Tablerows` are displayed as per SO Layout, you can take further long from here.

Comment: Many Many thanks ...it will great helpful for me :) @Vikalp Patel

Comment: How can i manage border between text4 and text5 ? @Vikalp Patel

Comment: @jubayer_sust : Please see my updated answer which have additionally <View/> between text4 and text5 which gives you border alike

Answer (score 0):

You can use tablelayout. See this example http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-tablelayout-example/

Answer (score 0):

its quite simple. the `android:layout-weight` property should do the job.
but you also need the borders so we have to create a drawable to set the background for `TextView`s inside **/res/drawable** folder :

#### bg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#000" />

</shape>
```

and here is the activity's xml

#### layout_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/bg"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/hello_world" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/bg"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/hello_world" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/bg"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/hello_world" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/bg"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/hello_world" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/bg"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/hello_world" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/bg"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/hello_world" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/bg"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/hello_world" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/bg"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/hello_world" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/bg"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/hello_world" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/bg"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/hello_world" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/bg"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/hello_world" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

and this is how it looks:[image]

Hope its what you wanted `;)`